# How to create Google AdWord campaigns for a specific movie?

Tags: google-ads, ppc

I am trying to create a [ppc](/questions/tagged/ppc) [google-adwords](/questions/tagged/google-adwords) campaign targeting specific movies, e.g. for people searching to buy tickets for Blade Runner 2049 movie.

I am constructing keywords using the following pattern:

```
"{movie name}" {movie release year} "cinema tickets"
"{movie name}" {movie release year} "movie times"
"{movie name}" {movie release year} "movie showtimes"
"{movie name}" {movie release year} "movie theatre"
"{movie name}" {movie release year} "movie tickets online"
"{movie name}" {movie release year} "movie tickets"
"{movie name}" {movie release year} "near me"
"{movie name}" {movie release year} +cinemas
"{movie name}" {movie release year} +cineworld
"{movie name}" {movie release year} +showtimes
"{movie name}" {movie release year} +vue
```

A campaign for Blade Runner 2049 movie would therefore have the following keywords:

```
"Blade Runner 2049" 2017 "cinema tickets"
"Blade Runner 2049" 2017 "movie times"
"Blade Runner 2049" 2017 "movie showtimes"
"Blade Runner 2049" 2017 "movie theatre"
"Blade Runner 2049" 2017 "movie tickets online"
"Blade Runner 2049" 2017 "movie tickets"
"Blade Runner 2049" 2017 "near me"
"Blade Runner 2049" 2017 +cinemas
"Blade Runner 2049" 2017 +cineworld
"Blade Runner 2049" 2017 +showtimes
"Blade Runner 2049" 2017 +vue
```

The problem is that [google-adwords](/questions/tagged/google-adwords) ignores all of these keywords with an error:

> People don't search for this term very often, so it's not eligible to show your ads.

[image]

How I can create a [ppc](/questions/tagged/ppc) campaign targeting a specific movie?

Comment: In this case why do you have both "2049" and "2017" at the same time?   "Blade Runner 2049 tickets" or "Blade Runner 2017 tickets" should be enough to ensure that is the correct movie.

Comment: Actually, why are you trying to include the release year at all?   Nobody is buying tickets for old movies.   "blade runner tickets" is going to be for the newly released film, not for the old one.

Comment: Presence of the year is not the problem, though, is it? It is optional keyword.

Comment: No, it is not optional.   There is no such thing as an optional keyword in AdWords.   If you have it on "broad match" it may be replaced by a synonym or possibly matched by topic, but if you can omit it, you should.   On "broad match" or "phrase match" Google allows searchers to add *any* unspecified keyword.  That looks like a big part of why Google says nobody is searching.  You have over-specified your searches.

Answer (score 2):

You cant mix match types for keywords in Adwords eg phrase match and broad match.
However you could use modified broad match which gives you a little more control than just plain broad match.

> Broad match modifiers ensure that your ads will only show when
>   someone’s search is an exact match or close variant of your keyword.
>   Close variants include misspellings, singular and plural forms,
>   abbreviations and acronyms, and stemmings (like "floor" and
>   "flooring"). Synonyms (like "quick" and "fast") and related searches
>   (like "shoes" and "boots") aren't considered close variants.

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2497702?hl=en&ref_topic=3122868

Answer (score 1):

All advertisers know that this is a game of trial & error. A/B testing, refining, improving, and repeating the process. I am going to go out on a limb and recommend that you try Video Advertising. The targeting with video ads is incredibly precise, for example, you can target every user that has watched a specific channel on YouTube, and even a specific video on youtube. Knowing your audience is key. Given that youtube is the 2nd largest search engine - with more than 3 billion searches per month - not to mention the very thing that you are advertising for takes the form of video - give it a shot. If not this campaign, sooner or later we will all be forced to if we are to stay ahead of the game.